# Как немного переделать collapse bootstrap под свои задачи?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Никак не могу добиться такого результата как в макете ожидается 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить задачу:

1. По умолчанию первый активный пункт должен иметь ссылку active
2. При клике на второй пункт и вообще последующие пункты, предыдущий контент схлопывался бы.

Может есть другие аккордеоны, коллапсы, более универсальные чем от bootstrap?

Код примера:

```
<div class="terms-condition">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="item-1"><span>01</span> Definitions</li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="item-2"><span>02</span> Construction</li>
            <li>03 General</li>
            <li>04 Orders</li>
            <li>05 Price and payment</li>
            <li>06 Specification of Goods</li>
            <li>07 Delivery and risk</li>
            <li>08 Buyer's obligations</li>
            <li>09 Alterations to the Agreement</li>
            <li>10 Warranty</li>
            <li>11 Indemnity</li>
            <li>12 Limitation of liability</li>
            <li>13 Termination</li>
            <li>14 Intellectual property rights</li>
            <li>15 Force majeure</li>
            <li>16 Assignment</li>
            <li>17 Waiver</li>
            <li>18 Variation</li>
            <li>19 Severability</li>
            <li>20 Rights of third Parties</li>
            <li>21 Governing law</li>
        </ul>

    </aside>
    <article class="content">
        <div class=" collapse in" id="item-1">
            <h2>1. Definitions</h2>
            <p>In this document the following words shall have the following meanings:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse in" id="item-2">
            <h2>2. Construction</h2>
            <p>In these Conditions, the following rules apply:</p>
            2.1     A person includes a natural person, corporate or unincorporated body (whether or not they have separate legal personality).<br>

            2.2     A reference to a party includes its personal representatives, successors or permitted assigns.<br>

            2.3     A reference to 'writing' or 'written' includes faxes and emails.
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Пример на [codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-lenk/pen/gwZGVB)

Comment: Это не колапс, это акардион закрывает предыдущие и Вы сами указываете id того что нужно закрывать. Посмотрите доки повнимательней.

Comment: или же написать собственный, реализация не очень сложная

Comment: смотрел я в доки, нету там такого. Может есть где готовое решение?